# WPF Multithreading UI Lockup

Tags: .net, wpf

I am trying to create a load window which will have a progress bar and display this while the background worker does some time intensive work. Unfortunately, this load window only partially loads then freezes until the background work is completed. How can I fix this so that the load window does not conflict with the background processes?

A visual example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHXvv.png

---

```
        lw = new LoadWindow();
        lw.Show();            

        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            /*Program-specific code*/

            string theDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); /* get the folder location of the exe */
            string filePath = theDirectory + "\\export.xml";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                FileStream f = File.Create(filePath);
                f.Close();
            }

            FileStream fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
            fileStream.SetLength(0);
            fileStream.Close();

            FileStream fsWrite = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsWrite);

            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { 

                /*Program-specific code*/                    

                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C svn log " + FolderPath.Text + " -v --xml");
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                using (System.Diagnostics.Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {

                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {
                        string outStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        sw.Write(outStr);
                        sw.Close();
                        fsWrite.Close();
                        reader.Close();
                        process.WaitForExit();
                    }
                }
                TicketIDChanged(sender, new TextChangedEventArgs(e.RoutedEvent, new UndoAction()));
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);             
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            lw.Hide();
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: What are you doing in the call to Dispatcher.Invoke?

Comment: Peter, i just updated my question to show what I am doing. In Dispatcher.Invoke, I call the svn xml command and write the output to a file.

Comment: Why not use StearWriter of another writer to output to file (not cmd.exe)?

Comment: All this code does is execute "svn xml" in the shell and write the output to a file. This is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

By using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` you are delegating all the work within the delegate onto the UI-Thread. If this is a time intensive operation it'll get stuck here.

Try to use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` for updating UI states only. If this isn't easily accessible, try to refactor your code and add multiple invocations.

You can also set `worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true` and use the `worker.ReportProgress(int percent, object args)` method to update a simple progress bar on your loading screen. The dispatching will then be handled by the BackgroundWorker.

Try to invoke only the `TickedIDChanged`-method, for example.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I refactored the code inside Invoke() other than TicketIDChanged() into a new method. Using a global variable to store the value of FolderPath.Text (and update the variable when the text changes) allowed me to do this without any errors since this was part of another thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` to run a big chunk of code (from StartProcess to WaitForExit) on the GUI thread. Yes that will block.

And I don't see the reason for the Invoke. Running a process is well suited for running in `DoWork()`.

The only part that needs syncing is the `TicketIDChanged()` at the end. Do that with `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or move it to the Completed event.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing the work on the UI thread not background. I might be wrong because im not 100% sure what the background priority means. However, what i would advise you try is to not do the async work inside a dispatcher invoke... And if part of the async work is to assigment to something on the UI thread then do just the assignment in a dispatcher invoke inside the completed handler along with the hide like you do.

Comment: The reason I use Invoke is that if I do not, I get an exception saying that the 'calling thread does not own the resource' or something like that.

Comment: Well yeah, exactly what i said. Parts of ur async code is referencing something on the UI thread, like a textbox or a button or even a list bound to a datagrid. Those parts need to be in dispatcher invokes. Only those parts.

Answer (score 0):

With the .NET 4.0 release, we got the Task Parallel Library (TPL) which provided APIs for performing Parallel and Task Based Asynchronous Operations. The TPL provides classes like Task and Parallel which were used for performing asynchronous programming and parallel operations respectively. In .NET 4.5 with C# 5.0 we got the async and await keywords for representing asynchronous methods. In WPF, we can make use of the Task class for creating responsive and interactive applications.